# How to get the lowest and highest values for interval class

Tags: r

My data looks like the following data:

```
df<-read.table(text = "temp
12
15
12
6
9
11
15
14
14
16
14
14
11
12
13
14
10
12
12
14
9
13
12
15
11
11
12
12
10
11",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the lowest and highest levels for temp to calculate cumulative.

I have done the following codes:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(names(df),~df %>% 
count(!!rlang::sym(.x)%>% 
mutate(cum=cumsum(temp)/sum(temp)))
```

AS you can see, this gives us the temps of  6,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, but 7 and 8 is lacking.

I want to have the following output:

```
temp    n   cum
6   x   x
7   0   x
8   0   x
9   x   x
10  x   x
11  x   x
12  x   x
13  x   x
14  x   x
15  x   x
16  x   x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `complete` to fill the missing sequence in `temp` and `fill` the `cum` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 count(temp) %>% 
 mutate(cum=cumsum(n)/sum(n)) %>%
 complete(temp = seq(min(temp), max(temp)), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
 fill(cum)

# A tibble: 11 x 3
#    temp     n    cum
#   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     6     1 0.0333
# 2     7     0 0.0333
# 3     8     0 0.0333
# 4     9     2 0.1   
# 5    10     2 0.167 
# 6    11     5 0.333 
# 7    12     8 0.6   
# 8    13     2 0.667 
# 9    14     6 0.867 
#10    15     3 0.967 
#11    16     1 1
```

Comment: Not sure , why Cum are not consistent with Excel

Comment: @user1946911 I am not sure about your expected output. Please check the updated answer if that is what you want.

Comment: @user1946911 I see. You actually needed `cumsum` of `n` and not `temp`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could use `table` to get `df2`, `match` the frequencies `within` a new `data.frame` out of the temperature `range`, where you set `NA` to zero, ans calculate the `cumsum`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(table(df$temp))
rg <- range(df$temp)
res <- within(data.frame(temp=rg[1]:rg[2]), {
  n <- df2[match(temp, df2$Var1), "Freq"]
  n[is.na(n)] <- 0
  cum=cumsum(n/sum(n))
})[c(1, 3, 2)]
res
#    temp n        cum
# 1     6 1 0.03333333
# 2     7 0 0.03333333
# 3     8 0 0.03333333
# 4     9 2 0.10000000
# 5    10 2 0.16666667
# 6    11 5 0.33333333
# 7    12 8 0.60000000
# 8    13 2 0.66666667
# 9    14 6 0.86666667
# 10   15 3 0.96666667
# 11   16 1 1.00000000
```